# Click item in listview does not work

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-adapter, onitemclicklistener

When I click on any list item nothing happens, can someone please help or tell me where the problem is...?

**Here is my Listview:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".defineBybeldbAlles">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/BybelHoofstukListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#ff303030"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is my Listview Item:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/customButtonLayout"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_width="200dp">

            <! hoofstuk_id is hidden and is only for reference >
            <TextView
                android:text="id"
                android:id="@+id/hoofstuk_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:text="nommer"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/custom_row_hoofstuktext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

**Here is my OnItemclicklistener in  the activity:**

```
 listviewHoofstuk.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

@Override
public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2, long arg3){

//on selecting a hoofstk
//BybelActivityVers will be launched to show verse inside

Intent hoofstukIntent = new Intent(BybelActivityHoofstuk.this,BybelActivityVers.class);

//send hoofstuk_id to VersActivity to get verse under that book

String hoofstuk_id_na_vers =((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.hoofstuk_id)).getText().toString();
hoofstukIntent.putExtra("hoofstuk_id", hoofstuk_id_na_vers);

startActivity(hoofstukIntent);
}
});
```

Ive looked at a few other solutions but nothing works in my case, I added this code but it makes no difference when I use it or not:

```
android:focusable="false"

android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Comment: Post your adapter class please

Comment: Are you getting any error?..or have you try to debug and find out whether its going inside the method or not??

Comment: Remove these _android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"_. No need to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

and then applied

```
android:clickable="false"
```

it did not work but after fiddling around I found that

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

in combination did the trick!

This was applied in the **listview item** just after **LinearLayout**.

I tested and can confirm it works with Gridview as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yout list item is taking focus. Set below line in **LinearLayout** Tag in **`my Listview Item xml`** file

```
 android:clickable="false"
```

Your intent will fire without taking focus and work properly I ahve checked it... Let me know once its works for you...

Comment: I removed `android:focusable="false"

android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` and then applied your code, it didnt work so I put back android:focusable="false" and it worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use AdapterView to get adpater item views here you should use **parent** to find TextView

```
listviewHoofstuk.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //on selecting a hoofstk
                //BybelActivityVers will be launched to show verse inside

                Intent hoofstukIntent = new Intent(BybelActivityHoofstuk.this,BybelActivityVers.class);

                //send hoofstuk_id to VersActivity to get verse under that book
                String hoofstuk_id_na_vers =((TextView)parent.findViewById(R.id.hoofstuk_id)).getText().toString();
                hoofstukIntent.putExtra("hoofstuk_id", hoofstuk_id_na_vers);
                startActivity(hoofstukIntent);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".defineBybeldbAlles">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/BybelHoofstukListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#ff303030"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In your listview item you have to make this changes:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/customButtonLayout"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
        android:layout_width="200dp">

        <! hoofstuk_id is hidden and is only for reference >
        <TextView
            android:text="id"
            android:id="@+id/hoofstuk_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:text="nommer"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/custom_row_hoofstuktext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This should solve your question if not just hit comment on this answer. After that you will start getting OnItemClick() event of listview.